# Chave primária composta usando uma chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

É possível criar uma chave primária composta utilizando uma chave estrangeira?

Tenho a tabela `mov_estoque`, onde pensei em colocar como chave composta o `id_mov` e `id_prod`, porém, `id_prod` é uma chave estrangeira da tabela produtos.

tentei:

```
ALTER TABLE mov_estoque
DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id,id_pro);
```

mas recebo:

> 1832 - Cannot change column 'id_pro': used in a foreign key constraint 'mov_estoque_ibfk_2'

Comment: Por que ela tem que ser composta? Talvez uma tabela de movimentação e uma auxiliar relacionando n para n movimentação-produtos ficaria mais coeso no modelo, assim vc teria a movimentação em separado e os produtos desta movimentação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE NomeDaTabela
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NomeDaPK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Coluna1, Coluna2)
```

Caso queira adicionar a PK durante a criação da tabela, use esta sintaxe:

```
CREATE TABLE NomeDaTabela (
   Coluna1 INT,
   Coluna2 INT,
   CONSTRAINT PK_NomeDaPK PRIMARY KEY (Coluna1, Coluna2)
)
```